# Can you specify a try handler without a catch or finally block in ES?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, try-catch

Is there a way to define a try block without a catch in JavaScript?

The compiler complains with the following code:

```
try {
    const newAPI = require("applicationutils");
}
```

FYI Month after month new APIs are introduced. In my case if an API is available I want to a new course of action. If they aren't available I'll use the default settings. I don't need a catch block. I just want to know if it's possible.

If the class doesn't exist the code throws an error so it has to be wrapped in a catch block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to use a `try` without `catch` and/or `finally`. As per [MDN try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch):

> The `try` statement consists of a `try` block, which contains one or more
>   statements. `{}` must always be used, even for single statements. At
>   least one `catch` clause, or a `finally` clause, must be present. This
>   gives us three forms for the `try` statement:
>
> ```
> try...catch
> try...finally
> try...catch...finally
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as shown below where "block scopes" are defined inline in your function body which effectively achieves what you require.

These are defined by `{ .. }` directly in your function, and introduce new portions of lexical/variable scope to your function where for instance, a variable can be defined that's only accessible inside of that block's scope.

Exceptions can be thrown from within these inline block scopes, and will be caught by a `catch` handler defined at a prior point in your call stack:

```
function foo() {
    /* Start a block scope in function foo() */
    {
        /* newAPI only accessible in this block scope */
        const newAPI = require("applicationutils");
    }

    /* Start another block scope, defined in same function foo() */
    {           
        /* newAPI is unique to this block, the newAPI variable name
           can be re-used seeing it's unique in the lexical scope */
        const newAPI = { getUsers : () => [] };

       /* Throwing an exception from block scope is okay - it does not
          need to be handled with a catch() clause on this block, and
          will be handled by an optional catch() clause lower in the 
          call stack */
       throw new Error('throwing from second block scope in foo()');
    }
    /* no catch(..) {} clause is syntactically required */
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts yes sure can - please see updated answer. Hope that helps :)